# Find out which the user filled out

Tags: php

I'm trying to figure out how to find out where I need to do the steps if it was the username or if it was the email address the user filed out.

```
// Assign variable values if there is values
if ((isset($_POST['username'])) && ($_POST['username'] !== NULL) && (!empty($_POST['username']))) { $username = trim($_POST['username']); }
if ((isset($_POST['email'])) && ($_POST['email'] !== NULL) && (!empty($_POST['email']))) { $email = trim($_POST['email']); }


// IF BOTH FIELDS ARE EMPTY, ERROR CONDITION EXISTS
if (empty($username) && empty($email)) { 

    $errors = "yes";
    $message = "You must enter a value for either the username or email address!";

    $output = array('errorsExist' => true, 'message' => $message);

} else if (!empty($username) && !empty($email)) {

    $errors = "yes";
    $message = "You can only enter a value for the username or email address!";

    $output = array('errorsExist' => true, 'message' => $message);        

} else {

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// Assign variable values if there is values
if ((isset($_POST['username'])) && ($_POST['username'] !== NULL) && (!empty($_POST['username']))) { $username = trim($_POST['username']); }
if ((isset($_POST['email'])) && ($_POST['email'] !== NULL) && (!empty($_POST['email']))) { $email = trim($_POST['email']); }


// IF BOTH FIELDS ARE EMPTY, ERROR CONDITION EXISTS
if (empty($username) && empty($email)) { 

    $errors = "yes";
    $message = "You must enter a value for either the username or email address!";

    $output = array('errorsExist' => true, 'message' => $message);

} else if (!empty($username) && !empty($email)) {

    $errors = "yes";
    $message = "You can only enter a value for the username or email address!";

    $output = array('errorsExist' => true, 'message' => $message);        

} else {
   if(!empty($username)) {
        //Do some things if the user entered only the username
   }
   else {
        //Do some things if the user entered only email
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you too for the quick response.

Comment: No problem.  I just realized I forgot a '$' on the username variable.  It's fixed now.

Answer (score 2):

```
else if ( empty( $username ) ) {
    // Output username error
}
else if ( empty( $email ) ) {
    // Output email error
}
```

In this case, however, I would skip the if/else statements, and just use an error condition:

```
$is_error = false;
if ( empty( $username ) ) {
    $is_error = true;
    $error_messages[] = 'Your username error message';
}
if ( empty( $email ) ) {
    $is_error = true;
    $error_messages[] = 'Your email error message';
}

if ( $is_error ) {
    // Output all error messages
}
else {
    // Perform success event
}
```

Comment: Wow that was a quick response. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to do your steps in the last `else` that will execute only if neither username and email are empty or inputted. So in the last else, you can do something like

```
if (!empty($username)) {
} else {
}
```

On another note, I think you do not need to all the 3 checks when populating $username or $email; the first and the last should suffice, like:

```
if (isset($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['username']) {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
}
```